# Show that this function is measurable

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $f$ be a measurable function, and define $g(x)=0$ if $f(x)$ is rational and $g(x)=1$ if $f(x)$ is irrational. Prove the $g$ is measurable.

So what has to be proved is that for any open set $I \subset \mathbb{R}$, $g^{-1}(I)$ is a measurable set. But what does that mean? Well sure I know what that means, it's that the set in question is among those of "the" $\sigma$-algebra, but here's my problem: we have $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g:f(X) \subset \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \{0,1\}$. So, $g^{-1}(I)$ has to be shown to be a measurable set in some $\sigma$-algebra on $f(X)$. I cannot comprehend this.

I thought about simply looking at what $g^{-1}(I)$ could look like for various choices of $I$. If neither $0$ nor $1$ are in $I$ then $g^{-1}(I)$ is empty. If only $0 \in I$ then $g^{-1}(I)$ contains only rationals, if only $1 \in I$ then $g^{-1}(I)$ contains only irrationals, and if $I$ contains both $0$ and $1$ then $g^{-1}(I)$ can contain any real number. Supposing for a minute we can look at this "in" $\mathbb{R}$, how would I show that, say, the rationals is in the relevant $\sigma$-algebra?

Answer (score 1):

> here's my problem: we have $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g:f(X) \subset \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \{0,1\}$. So, $g^{-1}(I)$ has to be shown to be a measurable set in some $\sigma$-algebra on $f(X)$.

Actually, no: since $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ one has $g:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, not  $g:f(X) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

To prove that $g$ is measurable, a shortcut is to note that $g=h\circ f$ where $h: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is the indicator function of $\mathbb Q$. Since $\mathbb Q$ is measurable, $h$ is measurable, hence $h\circ f$ is measurable as the composition of measurable functions for the suitable sigma-algebras.

Comment: Don't you mean $h$ is the indicator function on $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$?

Answer (score 0):

If $I$ contains $0$ and not $1$, then $g^{-1}(I)$ is not the rationals. It is $f^{-1}(\mathbb{Q})$, the $f$-inverse image of the rationals. This is measurable because $\mathbb{Q}$ is a Borel set, so $f^{-1}(\mathbb{Q})$, as the inverse image of a Borel set under a measurable function, is measurable.

A similar argument will work for the other cases.